# Question regarding equality of $\sigma$-algebras (subsets of $\Bbb R^n$).

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

Consider the following question:

Let $E$ be a subset of $\Bbb R^n$ and let $\mathcal{B}(E)$ denote the Borel $\sigma-$algebra of $E$. Show that

1. $\mathcal{B}(E) = E \cap \mathcal{B}(\Bbb R^n)$
2. If $E \in \mathcal{B}$, then $\mathcal{B}(E) = \{B \in \mathcal{B}(\Bbb R^n) \colon B \subset E\}.$

**My attempt.** I was able to prove claim $1.$ (there are also other questions on MSE that approach this same problem). As for claim $2.$, I am not sure how to proceed (I haven't found questions that answer this precise claim on MSE). Follows my attempt:

From $1.$, we know that $\mathcal{B}(E) = E \cap \mathcal{B}(\Bbb R^n)$ and thus it suffices to show that $E \cap \mathcal{B}(\Bbb R^n) = \{ B \in \mathcal{B}(\Bbb R^n) \colon B \subset E\}.$

Inclusion $(\supset)$ follows directly, since for any $B \in \mathcal{B}(\Bbb R^n)$ such that $B \subset E$ we have that $B = E \cap B \in (E \cap \mathcal{B}(\Bbb R^n)).$

The other inclusion is the one that's giving me quite some problems: take some arbitrary element $E \cap B_1$, for $B_1 \in \mathcal{B}(\Bbb R^n).$ It is clear that $E \cap B_1 \subset E,$ but how does one show that $E \cap B_1 \in \mathcal{B}(\Bbb R^n)$ ?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\{B \in \mathcal{B}(\Bbb R^n) \colon B \subset E\}$ is a $\sigma-$ algebra of subsets of $E$. Any open set in $E$ is of the form $E\cap U$ where $U$ is open in $\mathbb R^{n}$. Hence, $\{B \in \mathcal{B}(\Bbb R^n) \colon B \subset E\}$ contains all open subsets of $E$ and this implies that it contains all Borel subsets of $E$.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I am missing something but I don't see how your answer clarifies my specific question: I understand that to show $\mathcal{B}(E) \subset \{B \in \mathcal{B}(\Bbb R^n) \colon B \subset E\}$ it suffices to show that the latter set contains all open sets of $E$. Such open sets are of the form $E \cap U,$ with $U$ being open in $\Bbb R^n.$ Clearly, $E \cap U \subset E$ and thus all we have to show is that $E \cap U \in \mathcal{B}(\Bbb R^n).$ This is where I am stuck! I don't think this is very explicit in your answer (at least for me).

Comment: In 2) you have written $E \in \mathcal B$? What is $\mathcal B$? This should be $\mathcal B (\mathbb R^{n})$. Since $E$ and $U$ are both in $\mathcal B (\mathbb R^{n})$ so is their intersection. @xyz

Comment: You are correct. Thank you for your help, very clarifying.